# Spring Boot created @Bean with interface the @PostConstruct not called with native image

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, postconstruct

Spring Boot 3.1.3
graalvm-jdk-17.0.8+9.1

When creating bean manually from configuration and return interface the bean @PostConstruct is NOT called.
The workaround I found is to return implementing class and not interface.
Without native image same works without workaround.
Not sure if expected or a BUG ?

```
public interface MyBean {
}

public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    // when returning MyBeanImpl it works fine
    @Bean 
    public MyBean myBean() { 
        return new MyBeanImpl();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is expected, as when inspecting what to do the only thing that is available for analysis is the method return type. Which is your interface and doesn't hold the annotated method. Always be as specific as possible for your `@Bean` return types.

Comment: I would agree to that if that does not work in regular mode, however, with regular Spring Boot and JVM same code works fine, only in native image it does not.

Comment: Because the inspection can be delayed, to generate the native code it cannot that only has the static data available from method inspection.